# Predicting Rain (Probability)

Tags: probability

> In London, 60% of the days have some rain.
>
> Alice is a weather forecaster in London. Her rain forecasts are correct $\dfrac 23$ of the time.
>
> That is, the probability that it rains, given that Alice has predicted rain, and the probability that it does not rain, given that Alice has predicted that it won't rain, are both equal to $\dfrac 23$.
>
> Find the probability that, on a randomly chosen day, Alice predicts rain.

I don't know how to approach this kind of problem. I can only think of doing $\dfrac{2}{3}$ of $60\%$, which doesn't seem right and looks too simple for an answer.

Comment: Your clarification in the 3rd paragraph ($P(R|A)=P(not R|not A)=2/3$) is not the same as the condition in the 2nd paragraph ($P(A=R)=2/3$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ be the event that there is rain.

Let $F$ be the event that the forecast is rain.

We are given:
$$P(R) = 60\% \tag1$$
$$P(R|F) = \dfrac23 \tag2$$
$$P(\neg R|\neg F) = \dfrac23 \tag3$$

We extend $(2)$ and $(3)$ to form:
$$P(\neg R|F) = \dfrac13 \tag4$$
$$P(R|\neg F) = \dfrac13 \tag5$$

Now, we need to find $P(F)$.

Let $P(F) = x$.

Then, $P(R \land F) = P(R|F) P(F) = \dfrac23x$.

Also $P(R \land \neg F) = P(R|\neg F) P(\neg F) = \dfrac13(1-x)$.

Finally:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
P(R \land F) + P(R \land \neg F) &=& P(R) \\
\dfrac23x + \dfrac13(1-x) &=& 60\% \\
\dfrac13x &=& \dfrac4{15} \\
x &=& \dfrac45
\end{array}$$

So the required probability is $\dfrac45$.

Answer (score 0):

If we take $30$ days, assume it rains on $18$ of them.

Alice correctly predicts the weather on $20$ of them.

This can consist of $18$ R's and $2$ NR's being the right choice (and so $10$ incorrect predictions of R), through to $8$ R's and $12$ NR's (and so $10$ incorrect predictions of NR).

In the first case Alice predicts R $28$ times, the case after $26$ times, through to the last case of $8$ times, which gives $198=(14\cdot15-6)\times2$ times. She can make $11$ different predictions, so she picks R $\frac{198}{11}=18$ times in $30$, which is $0.6$ probability.

Comment: Read the clarification in the third paragraph.